# How to play the given part without the left and right hand clashing?

Tags: sheet-music

How to play the 'E' note in bass clef (left hand)  without clashing with the 'D' note played in treble clef(right hand). 
Key is C. 
[image]

Comment: I would play it the same way as in the other bars.  Four eighths and a half. You shouldn‘t trust this arrangement anyway: This is no good notation. Look at the 2 bars the line below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean clashing harmonically?  That's the composer's prerogative.  If you mean clashing physically, it is fine.  Play the 'E' with the left hand above the right hand.  Note that rhythmically the E comes between the C and D.